# An Ode to Scary Ginkgo von Barry

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

What follows is a riddle and query:

> An ode to my cat 
> Ginkgo von Barry. 
> My sweet little cat 
> the neighbors find scary.
>
> The mailman’s so scared, 
> he will always tear, 
> and then he turns blue, 
> grinning ear to ear.
>
> “Why do they run” 
> little Joe, always asks, 
> “And why do the neighbors 
> disguise in masks?”
>
> Then one sad day 
> our Barry ran away. 
> We miss him dearly 
> every single day.
>
> He would guard our prized lawn 
> from dusk till dawn, 
> but then one morning, 
> he had up and gone.
>
> Why is my mother 
> flying into town? 
> What is so special 
> 'bout some “coffee groun'?”
>
> I don’t see how 
> this cheers in any way. 
> But wow, Joe, look!
> Kids are out to play!
>
> I hope you are safe 
> Ginkgo von Barry. 
> I hope you find friends 
> who are just as scary.

**How is this poor cat so very scary?**

**Why do the owners and neighbors views vary?**

**Should he cross your path,**
**what would call Ginkgo von Barry?**

> Hint:

> It's not a cat.

> Hint 2:

> He guards the lawn "from dusk till dawn". It's nocturnal.

Comment: rot13(Fubhyq V or guvaxvat nobhg Oneel Bonzn naq Wbr Ovqra?)

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon I had not intended that correlation. Lol.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with rot13(tvaxtb ovybon)?

Comment: @EdMurphy rot13(Ab, ohg Tvaxtb "Oneel" jnf n checbfrshyyl pubfra anzr.)

Comment: What about rot13(onevhz), or rot13(n crefba anzrq Oneel)?

Comment: @EdMurphy rot13(V chg "Tvaxtb Oneel" orpnhfr vg'f n anzr, ohg gur cebahapvngvba vf gur fnzr nf "Tvaxtb Oreel" juvpu vf jung gur "Png" jnf anzrq nsgre.)

Comment: Fb vg vfa'g eryngrq gb tvaxtb ovybon, ohg vg *vf* eryngrq gb tvaxtb oreel? Orpnhfr gubfr ner eryngrq gb rnpu bgure. Bxnl, qb nal bs gur sbyybjvat ersre gb *fcrpvsvp* crefbaf be cynprf: gur znvyzna, Wbr, gur ynja, gur cbrg'f zbgure, gur pbssrr, gur xvqf? Nyfb, qbrf guvf cregnva gb fcrpvsvp tvatxb gung fheivirq n pregnva rirag va gur avargrra-sbegvrf?

Comment: Fbeel, V jnf gelvat gb abg gb fvzcyl fnl vg, ohg creuncf V'z znxvat vg zber pbashfvat. Gur fbyhgvba ernyyl unf abguvat gb qb jvgu gur cynag, rkprcg gur "Png" unf na nggevohgr fvzvyne gb "Tvaxtb Oreelf", naq fb vg jnf anzrq "Tvaxtb iba Oneel".

Comment: Gur onq fzryy? Znlor gur "png" vf npghnyyl n fxhax? Fbzr bs gur arvtuobef znl unir n cbbere frafr bs fzryy. Qhaab ubj "pbssrr tebha'" jbhyq svg va.

Comment: Lbh tbg vg! Fxhaxf jrer zvfgnxra sbe "Cbyrpngf" onpx va gur qnl, naq fbzr crbcyr fgvyy pnyy gurz gung zvfgnxrayl fnlvat "gung'f nabgure anzr sbe fxhax". Naq lrf, V qb gel gb vzcyl gur bjaref unir ab frafr bs fzryy, urapr gurve pbashfvba, naq shegure pbashfvba nobhg uvf zbz'f hetrapl gb evq ure fbaf ubzr bs gur fzryy jvgu (creuncf n abg gbb pbzzba xabja hfntr bs) pbssrr tebhaqf gb nofbeo onq fzryy.

Comment: Gurer vf nyfb n fyvtug vzcyvpngvba gung abobql unf gbyq gurz gung gurl unir ab frafr bs fzryy (jnf zbz furygrevat, naq sryg thvyg fb jnf fur gelvat gb svk vg?), be ng yrnfg gurl fvzcyl qb abg haqrefgnaq gur pbaprcg bs fzryy (va fcvgr bs vafgehpgvba) urapr gur pbashfvba  (abg xabjvat pbssrr fzryyf tbbq, guvaxvat vg vf whfg na bqq nggrzcg gb purre gurz hc). Nyy guvf cnvag gur pbashfrq fgbel fheebhaqvat guvf bqq "png".

Comment: @EdMurphy Nabgure uvag jnf gung ur thneqf gur ynja "sebz qhfx gvyy qnja". Vg'f abpgheany.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that Ginkgo von Barry

> crossed the border to France, where he became better known as Pepe le Peu.

As the author has since revealed in hints/comments,

> "polecats" smell bad (much like the trees of Ginkgo's namesake, the ginkgo berry), though not everyone is equally sensitive to it. Masks help block bad smells, and coffee contains nitrogen which helps neutralize them.

> Skunks are also active during the night.